# Cuántos campos son los recomendados para una tabla en una base de datos

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy con una gran duda... Consultando en varios sitios leí que una tabla tiene la capacidad de crear como máximo 4096 campos, ahora bien, mi pregunta es: por el tema de optimización, normalización y otros relacionados, cuántos campos son los correctos y lo óptimo para crear en una tabla por ejemplo la de usuarios? 10 campos, doce, 20, 60 campos,.... Cuántos campos...?

Un ejemplo sería por decir así que una tabla usuarios se relaciona por ejemplo con país, estado, municipio, categoría, género, religión, profesión, cargo, demografía. Cada una son tablas...

Entonces... cuantos campos puedo tener en una tabla???

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No existe una respuesta única y en todo caso la mas acertada viene de que normalices correctamente, por lo demás lo que te podamos decir son meras opiniones. Entonces estudia mucho *sobre normalización de bases de datos*

Comment: Los suficientes que necesites, siempre y cuando no exista reduncia de datos. Por ejemplo en la tabla alumnos puede existir un campo grado y grupo, y si creas otra tabla por ejemplo materia y quieres meter al alumno dentro no vas a crear otra vez el campo grado y grupo, sino que mandas a llamar la tabla de los datos del alumno

Comment: Buenos días... Entiendo lo de normalización, todo esta milimetricamente diseñado para dejar un modelo óptimo en mis tablas, no hay redundancia de datos, ninguno se repite y tengo mis tablas perfectamente relacionadas, solo que alguien me comentó que una tabla no puede tener mas de 16 campos y eso creó mi duda (me pregunté que fue lo que me perdí o no ví), por lo cual decidí investigar mejor y en realidad doy mi visto bueno a lo que me dices Arnoldo Rodas Perez, tiene mas lógica. Muchas gracias a los dos por sus respuestas tan puntuales.

Comment: No siempre el problema es la redundancia, sino la inconsistencia. Por otro lado, existen casos legítimos para las relaciones 1:1, a veces el desempeño se pelea con el modelado. Y por cierto, es mas apropiado hablar de *campos* en interfaces gráficas, y de *columnas* -incluso *atributos*- en bases de datos.